# Как мне сделать в моей разметке кликабельную правую часть?

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня есть разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F2F2F2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/service_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_of_service"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/service_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/name_of_service"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_descr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_back"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textColor="#666666" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

это item recyclerView. Я пытаюсь сделать кликабельной правую часть этого item-a -  думал через layout_weight но получилась ересь. Пробовал забросить в одельный linear layout и дальше уже играться как-то с ним, но тоже не получилось. Других идей у меня нет чтобы сделать адекватную реализацию. Может у кого есть какие-то идеи?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось перевести все в `constraint_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/testClick"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/service_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_of_service"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/service_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/testClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/relLay"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/relLay"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_descr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_back"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relLay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textColor="#666666" />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

теперь все как нужно. Может кому поможет :)

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout переделать в constraintLayout -> добавить frameLayout в правую часть и повесить на него клик

Comment: поменял linear на constraint, запустил - не подходит, список отображается некорректно

Comment: а элементы привязали в constraintLayout? https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/489-urok-180-constraintlayout-osnovy.html

Comment: я честно говоря не работал с этим видом макетов, и поэтому мне не очень понятно как перепилить мою разметку :) я планировал сделать это средствами linear

Comment: средствами linear тоже можно. Рутовый linear делаете horizontal, в него вкладываете новый linear vertical, в который вкладываете все остальное. А в рутовый кладете еще frameLayout, на который вешаете клик. Но это большая вложенность, тем более на списке - может сказаться на производительности.

Comment: horisontal нельзя, там внизу при нажатии на кнопку будет появляться еще один item :(

Comment: layout_descr будет вложен в вертикальный linear, который вложен в горизонтальный рутовый linear

Comment: теперь я вообще запутался

Comment: LinearLayout(horizontal) -> в нем LinarLayout(vertical) и FrameLayout. В LinearLayout(vertical) - ваши RelativeLayout и Linearlayout(layout_descr)